# How can I get the value of inheritance class of other inheritance class in .NET Roslyn API?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, roslyn, code-inspection

Good day,
I've been trying to get the value of inheritance class name of other inheritance class in Roslyn API.

like below picture,
[image]

when I'm scanning the 'Face' class, I want to get the name of "Human".
like this structure, I can get the first inheritance class name by using ClassDeclaration.BaseList. I can get the name of "Head" from Face class!

[image]

But I can't access the second inheritance class(Human class). I think that there's no more tree structure in Face class.

The question point is that the way how to get 2-layer upper(or more) inheritance class name if in case of the classes are seperated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the code you're using to access the base class?  If this is just code inspection in the IDE, go to the Head class and inspect BaseList there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. this is not a just code inspection in the IDE. I'm using sonarqube(source code inspection tool). this tool make the c# project to build in order to inspect the source code when the code inspection run. but as far as I know, Roslyn API is based on syntax tree. so I think there's no way to access the most highest inheritance relationship's class name. If you know another way to get the value, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the SemanticModel for your tree, then call GetDeclaredSymbol() with the ClassDeclarationSyntax. That'll give you the ITypeSymbol and you can look at BaseType from there. You don't want to try this with syntax only because of partial classes.

Comment: I've solved this problem. I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

create a recursive function on BaseList property of SyntaxNode. somthing like this

```
private static bool IsDrivedFromHead(ClassDeclarationSyntax syntax)
        {
            if (syntax.BaseList == null)
                return false;
            if (!syntax.BaseList.Types.Any(a => a.Type.ToString() == "Namespace.Head"))
            {
                bool IsDrived = false;
                foreach (var baseType in syntax.BaseList.Types)
                {
                    var node = (CompilationUnitSyntax)baseType.SyntaxTree.GetRoot();
                    foreach (ClassDeclarationSyntax member in node.Members.Where(w=> w is ClassDeclarationSyntax))
                    {
                        IsDrived = IsInheritFromHead(member);
                        if (IsDrived)
                            break;
                    }
                    if (IsDrived)
                        break;
                }
                return IsDrived;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
```